# Synonym not appearing in list

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, tag-synonyms

The [colors](/questions/tagged/colors) tag, according to Stack Overflow, [has 1 synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/colors/synonyms).

[image]

However, when I try to go to the [colour](/questions/tagged/colour) tag, I get redirected to [colors](/questions/tagged/colors). Therefore, I'm assuming [colour](/questions/tagged/colour) is a synonym of [colors](/questions/tagged/colors), but it doesn't show up in the synonym list. This also happens with [colours](/questions/tagged/colours).

What is happening?

Answer (score 1):

[colours](/questions/tagged/colours) and [colour](/questions/tagged/colour) are both synonyms of [color](/questions/tagged/color), which is in turn a synonym to [colors](/questions/tagged/colors). I don't believe synonyms like this can be created anymore (you can't suggest a synonym which already has synonyms itself (not sure if it applies to moderators too)), but previous ones were never really cleaned up because they didn't really cause problems other than not appearing in the list for the master tag.