# Community activates question how?

Tags: discussion, recent-activity, community-user

The question [Synonym not appearing in list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167504/) hasn't been touched lately, but in the [Active Questions Queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=active) it appears on the top edited by the *Community♦* user.

[image: Active Question Queue]

- What happened to that post that it got in the queue?
- Why was the *Community♦* user involved?

Comment: Those are just automatic community bumps for unanswered questions.

Comment: Sometimes Community also handles deletions, though I don't think it was that in this case.

Comment: @Mysticial: But the question has an answer. It is even upvoted.

Comment: @juergend That upvote was cast *after* it was bumped.

Comment: That was actually me and I can vouch that is was cast *after* Community bumped it.